# "IOError: cannot identify image file" while saving file content to ImageField in Django

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail, imagefield

How to save generated file content to `ImageField` in Django?
My current code is:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

image = create_screenshot(url)
print type(image) # <type 'str'>
screenshot = ScreenshotModel(...)
screenshot.image.save('filename.jpg', ContentFile(image), save=True)
```

This produces **no errors while saving**, but gives error while trying to show image (using `sorl.thumbnail`):

```
IOError: cannot identify image file <cStringIO.StringI object at 0x7fda5322c140>
```

File is being saved on disk properly, but it is not image and I cannot display it. I have checked file mime type and it is `application/octet-stream`.

Function `create_screenshot` generates image using `PhantomJS` and returns  raw output of `phantomjs` script - when I use it to generate PDF documents  and saving it to `FileField` everything is ok.

Comment: What does the function create_screenshot look like? It clearly doesn't return the screenshot in jpeg format. You should use pillow or something like that to convert the image to jpeg before saving.

Comment: If the screenshot is returned in png format, you could also just save it as 'filename.png'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PILLOW image into StringIO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920728/convert-pillow-image-into-stringio)

Comment: please read the following answer in order to understand how cStringIO works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24920879/480424